# NSRegularExpression search within matched string for the same pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I use NSRegularExpression to find matched by a certain patter, which is visible in the snippet:

```
- (NSString *)functionPattern
{
    return @"[A-Za-z]{1,}\\([A-Za-z0-9,\\(\\)]{1,}\\)";
}

- (void)test
{
    NSString *formula = @"AVERAGE(G17,G18,AVERAGE(G20,G21,MIN(G30,G31)))";

    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression *functionRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[self functionPattern]
                                                                                   options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                     error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
        return;
    }

    NSArray *matches = [functionRegex matchesInString:formula options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, formula.length)];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < matches.count; i++) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *result = matches[i];
        NSString *match = [formula substringWithRange:result.range];
        NSLog(@"%@", match);
    }
}
```

My natural expectation was to get 3 matches: AVERAGE(...), AERAGE(...) and MIN(...). Surprisingly for me, i only get one match: `AVERAGE(G17,G18,AVERAGE(G20,G21,MIN(G30,G31)))`.

If the formula is `AVERAGE(G17,G18)+AVERAGE(G20,G21,MIN(G30,G31))`, i'll get 2 matches: `AVERAGE(G17,G18)` and `AVERAGE(G20,G21,MIN(G30,G31))`. In other words, after a match is found, a search for the pattern is not performed in the range of the matched string.

Please advice how to overcome this, and find all possible matches. Am i missing something simple here?

What i'm doing is parsing and evaluating math expressions. All works fine, except for the cases of nested functions. If i know all possible function names in advance, can that be utilised somehow?

I'm hoping to fine more or less elegant approach; if i can i'd like to avoid things like "stripping off function name and parentheses'"

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you can make a regex that does what you want, but you *can* strip off the function name and parentheses, and then run the regex again on the remaining text.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for the thought, i considered that as well. I wish i could avoid it though. I edited the question a bit, please check.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want, at least the way you want to.

Regular expressions are technically a type 3 grammar and cannot describe recursive languages; your math expressions can contain other math expressions.

You *could* do something along the line of what you say you don't want to do. For example you could match an expression containing just a single pair of balanced parentheses, so in `AVERAGE(G20,G21,MIN(G30,G31))` you could match `MIN(G30,G31)`. If you then replaced the match by a marker and matched again you could match the next level, etc. But this *not* a good way to do it.

General math expressions can be described by a type 2 grammar, and can be easily parsed using a recursive descent parser. Such parsers are very easy to write. Essentially you write down the grammar you wish to parse and then write a function for each production. Google will get you started down this route.

If you don't want to write the parser yourself you can use a parser generator, in which case you still need to write the grammar, or search for one of the math expression libraries.

HTH